# Need to catch and display the Stack overflow error message

Tags: wicket, stack-overflow

I am fetching some 17,500 records from DB and getting below stack overflow error exactly at the resultset execution step.

```
Query query = dbConnect
                .createQuery("select nitem from NItem nitem where nitem.id in ("+nitemIdStr+")");
        nitemList = query.getResultList();
```

Stack overflow error

```
Root cause:

java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:98)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.OrExpression.acceptVisit(OrExpression.java:99)


 Complete stack:

 org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at com.rambutan.test.ExportNew$3@17adeb on component [Form [Component id = ajaxexample]] threw an exception

at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:247)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:226)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:854)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:254)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:211)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:282)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:247)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:226)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:854)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:254)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:211)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:282)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
```

I need to catch this error and display it in UI with a message saying "The file export exceeding the stack limit, Please use filter conditions" instead of getting in stack overflow error in the browser. is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The example below worked for me on a testpage:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
        @Override
        public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception e) {
            return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(SomePage.class));
        }
    });
```

Add this in you `Application` and it will redirect you in case of an exception to `SomePage.class`.

But catching a stack overflow is bad practice. There are many ways to prevent this like limiting the query, limit input size, keep track of records processed or keep track of actual stack and finish it yourself.

So my suggestion is prevent the stack overflow instead of catching it in wicket.

Comment: i used createNativeQuery and it didn't give me any error.

Comment: Can you show what code calls you query? It looks like you have to many conditions based on user upload.

Comment: can we able to pass the error message to the errorpage.class using the above way??

I used your code and it took me to the errorpage.class but i want throw the message over there. Is there any way to do that??

Comment: Sure, use: `new PageProvider(new errorpage("Your message"))`. Add a constructor to errorpage which accepts a string and shows it.

Comment: But more importantly check the answer of [biziclop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24628267/2452275). This error should not happen ever. If you know an error can happen you should fix it, not catch the error.

Comment: i want to pass this message as a pageparameter, i tried this -->

    PageParameters page = new PageParameters();
    page.add("message",message)

   new PageProvider(new errorpage(page));

but i couldn't create pageparameters locally.

Comment: yes that should not happen ever, but its happening because am fetchin more objects and its exceeding the size. That is why am getting this error, so i should ask users to use filters instead of hitting entire db values, for that i must catch this error and show that in a meaningful way with a message saying "Please use filter values"

Comment: You can alway limit the results a query gives you, if you get the max number of results, warn the user that the maximum is reached and that they should use filters. The user should never be able to crash the system. To add PageParameters: `Page page = new errorPage(); page.getPageParameters().add("message", "BigError"); return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(page));`

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, catching errors is a bad idea because they usually mean that something was left in a severely inconsistent state.

Catching SOEs is particularly problematic, as there's no guarantee you'll be in a position to act on them. Although in your specific case, the stack will probably be empty enough when you catch it to allow you further calls, but it is possible that you trigger another SOE.

As an aside, you MUST NEVER EVER DO THIS:

```
Query query = dbConnect
            .createQuery("select nitem from NItem nitem where nitem.id in ("+nitemIdStr+")");
```

Seriously, don't.

[image]